# I need help to create search data using seleted value

Tags: php

I want to ask about this code. I have  two dropdown menu and one button. I want to search in sql database what I choose in those drop down menu. What is the sql syntax for search item in sql database by using two drop down menu.

This is my database = test
this is my table

Table = student

```
name  |   class    |  sex   | mark |
John  |   Five     | Male   | 75
Jashi |   Four     | Female | 89   |
```

This is my code

```
----------
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db ("test");

$whereClauses = '';
$class = count($_POST['class']);
$sex = count($_POST['sex']);
$i = 0;
if (! empty($_POST['class'])) {
foreach ($_POST['class'] as $class) {
$whereClauses .="class='".mysql_real_escape_string($class)."'";
if ($i++ == $class) {
$whereClauses .= " AND";
}
}
}
if (! empty($_POST['sex'])) {
foreach ($_POST['sex'] as $sex) {
$whereClauses .="sex='".mysql_real_escape_string($sex)."'";
}
if ($i++ == $sex) {
$whereClauses .= " AND";
}
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student '".$where."' ORDER BY id DESC '".$limit."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['class'];
echo $row['sex'];
echo $row['mark'];
}
?>


----------
HTML
<form action="search2.php" method="post">
<select name="class">
<option value="" selected="selected">Class</option>


</select>
<select name="sex">
<option value="" selected="selected">Sex</option>


</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what exactly you're asking. Does this code work?

Comment: Actually these code cant display data when clicked on search button...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this example easy and simple

**you got something like this**

```
<form method=post>
<?php
// some fetching over here like
$id = $_GET['id']; // getting id just for example
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT FROM `somewhere` where `id`='$id'");


<select name="somename">

 while($someid = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    ?>


    <option value="<?php echo $someid['id']; ?>"><?php echo $displayname; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>
   </select>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" /></form>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
    $search_id = $_POST['somename']; // value from option
    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `somewhere` WHERE `id`='$search_id'");
    // or you can use LIKE //
    // LIKE THIS //
    /*
    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `somewhere` WHERE `something` LIKE %SOMETHING%");
    */
    // Just example result down here //
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($search);
    echo '<table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th><th>SOMETHING</tH>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <Td>'.$result['name'].'</td><td>'.$result['something'].'</td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: that just can't be. i run this code first then posted here.. try include connection and see any logical error happens..

Answer (score 0):

```
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  mysql_select_db ("test");

  $whereClauses = '';

   if (! empty($_POST['class'])) {
       foreach ($_POST['class'] as $class) {
        $whereClauses[] .="class='".mysql_real_escape_string($class)."'";

       }
   }
   if (! empty($_POST['sex'])) {
      foreach ($_POST['sex'] as $sex) {
      $whereClauses[] .="sex='".mysql_real_escape_string($sex)."'";
      }
   }
   $where = !empty($whereClauses) ? implode(' and ', $whereClauses) : '';
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM student '".$where."' ORDER BY id DESC '".$limit."'";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['class'];
        echo $row['sex'];
        echo $row['mark'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your Solution is here, try this

```js
Database Table Structure
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mark` int(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Insert Record
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `class`, `sex`, `mark`) VALUES
('John', 'Five', 'Male', 75),
('Jashi', 'Four', 'Female', 89);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="class">
        <option value="">-SELECT CLASS-</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option>
    </select>
    <select name="sex">
        <option value="">-SELECT GENDER-</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db ("test");
extract($_POST);
if(isset($search))
{
 if($class!='' || $sex!='')
 {
  $wh='';
  if($class!='') $wh.=" AND class='".$class."'";
  if($sex!='')   $wh.=" AND sex='".$sex."'";
  $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where 1 ".$wh."");
  $total_record=mysql_num_rows($qry);
  if($total_record>0)
  {
   echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Class</td>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
     </tr>
     ";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
   {
    echo "<tr>
      <td>".$row['name']."</td>
      <td>".$row['class']."</td>
      <td>".$row['sex']."</td>
      <td>".$row['mark']."</td>
       </tr>";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   echo "No Record Found";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo "No Record Found";
 }
}
?>
```

Pls mark correct answer if your problem solved

Comment: Hello Safin, if you like my answer than pls mark this answer as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="class">
        <option value="">-SELECT CLASS-</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option>
    </select>
    <select name="sex">
        <option value="">-SELECT GENDER-</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db ("test");
extract($_POST);
if(isset($search))
{
 if($class!='' || $sex!='')
 {
  $wh='';
  if($class!='') $wh.=" AND class='".$class."'";
  if($sex!='')   $wh.=" AND sex='".$sex."'";
  $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where 1 ".$wh."");
  $total_record=mysql_num_rows($qry);
  if($total_record>0)
  {
   echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Class</td>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
     </tr>
     ";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
   {
    echo "<tr>
      <td>".$row['name']."</td>
      <td>".$row['class']."</td>
      <td>".$row['sex']."</td>
      <td>".$row['mark']."</td>
       </tr>";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   echo "No Record Found";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo "No Record Found";
 }
}
?>
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="class">
        <option value="">-SELECT CLASS-</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option>
    </select>
    <select name="sex">
        <option value="">-SELECT GENDER-</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db ("test");
extract($_POST);
if(isset($search))
{
 if($class!='' || $sex!='')
 {
  $wh='';
  if($class!='') $wh.=" AND class='".$class."'";
  if($sex!='')   $wh.=" AND sex='".$sex."'";
  $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where 1 ".$wh."");
  $total_record=mysql_num_rows($qry);
  if($total_record>0)
  {
   echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Class</td>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
     </tr>
     ";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
   {
    echo "<tr>
      <td>".$row['name']."</td>
      <td>".$row['class']."</td>
      <td>".$row['sex']."</td>
      <td>".$row['mark']."</td>
       </tr>";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   echo "No Record Found";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo "No Record Found";
 }
}
?>
```

Wow - what service! Thanks for the PROMPT response to my problem. Your code is working fine. I really do appreciate. Thanks